# Send email with html template programmatically

Tags: 7, emails

**On board:**

- Drupal 7
- Mail System
- Mime Mail

`mimemail-message.tpl.php` is configurated

E-mails sends by Rules with HTML template, but template not used when it call programmatically:

```
$mail = array(
  'subject' => 'Test e-mail',
  'message' => '
    <p>Lorem <a href="http://google.com">ipsum dolor sit amet</a>, consectetuer <b>adipiscing</b> elit, sed <i>diam</i> nonummy <s>nibh</s> euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  ',
);
drupal_mail('system', 'mail', 'to@example.com', language_default(), array('context' => $mail));
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you receive any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

In the `mimemail-message.tpl.php` info you can read

> Copy this file in your default theme folder to create a custom themed
>   mail.
>       Rename it to mimemail-message--[module]--[key].tpl.php to override it for a
>       specific mail.

Try to change your tpl name from 
`mimemail-message.tpl.php` to `mimemail-message--system.tpl.php`